# Ubuntu: Computer/Properties drive size doesn't match disk/partition size

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have ubuntu installed on an 8GB USB stick.

When I look at it with GParted, it says I have 3.94 MiB unallocated, and 7.31 GiB allocated to my dev/sdb1 partition. It also says that of that 7.31 GiB, 6.27 GiB is unused.

However, when I go to Computer > Properties, Ubuntu says my total capacity is 2.1 GB (out of which 1.9GB are used).

Where did my missing GB go, and how do I get them back?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your gparted output

Comment: I don't think any GB are missing: it's just the reporting of the size that's in error. Did you wait until the properties box scanned the whole disc counting files and sizes? What were the totals? How did these compare with what `df` reports?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's just the report- I first learned this was an issue when it said I had no more room to install software.

I don't know if this helps, but this is a bootable flash drive originally meant to install Ubuntu that I had to repurpose when my hard drive died.